# Transform multiple arrays of objects into a single array while merging the objects on common key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of objects that looks like this.

```
const myArray = [
  {
    values: [
      { date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3, "value2": 5 },
      { date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 8, "value2": 9 },
      { date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 4, "value2": 10 },
    ],
    customer: "Customer One"
  },
  {
    values: [
      { date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3 },
      { date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 5 },
      { date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 8 },
    ],
    customer: "Customer Two"
  }
];
```

All values of an object should be summed(by date) and then result as the value for the customer in the new object

What I want is it to look like this:

```
result = [
  { date: "2018-11-02", "Customer One": 8, "Customer Two": 3 },
  { date: "2018-11-01", "Customer One": 17, "Customer Two": 5 },
  { date: "2018-10-31", "Customer One": 14, "Customer Two": 8 },
]
```

I have working code for this but it feels way too complicated for what I need but I can't wrap my head around an easier way for some reason.

Here's my code (also on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zvlpm167x):

```
const myArray = [
  {
    values: [
      { date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3, "value2": 5 },
      { date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 8, "value2": 9 },
      { date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 4, "value2": 10 },
    ],
    customer: "Customer One"
  },
  {
    values: [
      { date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3 },
      { date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 5 },
      { date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 8 },
    ],
    customer: "Customer Two"
  }
];

const flatArray = myArray.flat();

const sumObjectKeysExceptDate = object => Object.keys(object).reduce((sum, key) => {
  if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(object[key], 10)) && key !== 'date') {
    return sum + parseInt(object[key], 10);
  }
  return sum;
}, 0);

const result = flatArray
  .reduce((acc, row) => [...acc, ...row.values.map(value => ({ [row.customer]: sumObjectKeysExceptDate(value), date: value.date }))], [])
  .reduce((acc, row) => {
    if (acc.find(innerrow => innerrow.date === row.date)) {
      return acc.map((innerrow) => {
        if (innerrow.date === row.date) {
          return { ...innerrow, ...row };
        }
        return innerrow;
      });
    }
    return [...acc, row];
  }, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

- Create an object with `date` as key and corresponding resulting object as value. And using `Object.values` get the final result
- To build the object, use `Array.reduce` on outer array and for each value of inner array, check whether the entry for date exists or not in object. If it exists update it else create a new entry in object.
- For each object in inner array, sum the values of all keys except date and set it in object corresponding to the `customer` name key.

```js
const myArray = [{values: [{ date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3, "value2": 5 },{ date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 8, "value2": 9 },{ date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 4, "value2": 10 },],customer: "Customer One"},{values: [{ date: "2018-11-02", "value1": 3 },{ date: "2018-11-01", "value1": 5 },{ date: "2018-10-31", "value1": 8 },],customer: "Customer Two"}];

let result = Object.values(myArray.reduce((a,c) => {
  c.values.forEach(({date, ...rest}) => {
    a[date] = a[date] || {date};
    a[date][c.customer] = Object.values(rest).reduce((d,e) => d + e);
  });
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```